# PHP Regex between two tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm pretty horrible at regex and have tried learning all of the parameters for it but can never get it right, I have my code here and it just isn't working... Can anyone spot my error?

Also if you'd like to see the page source, just uncomment out the echo($out); and you can view the link between the tags. Thanks a lot guys!

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$delimiter = '#';
$startTag = '<img height=".*" src="';
$endTag = '" width=".*">';
$out = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/search?q=images&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=-6MjU6z_BMTerAHRvoCYDg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=664");
$regex = $delimiter . preg_quote($startTag, $delimiter) 
                    . '(.*?)' 
                    . preg_quote($endTag, $delimiter) 
                    . $delimiter 
                    . 's';
$AllImages = preg_match_all($regex,$out,$image);
foreach($AllImages as $Link) {
echo($Link[$i] . "\n");
$i++;
}
//echo($out); to get the tag <img height=".*" src="     and    " width=".*">
```

Comment: Yes sir I am, It's reading the google images page source and getting every image thumbnail link.

Edit: Well he deleted his comment.

Comment: Although regex can't be used to parse general HTML, for specific cases such as his, it can be possible.

Comment: If you `preg_quote` the `$startTag` and `$endTag`, its contained `.*` placeholders will no longer function as such. Also, if unversed with regex; it's not the simplest tool to apply to HTML extraction.

Comment: If you're trying to use regex to analyze HTML, you're much better off not.  Instead, there are great XML parsing tools that will do the job very well.  By the way, if you're trying to scrape thumbnails from Google Images, you'd better have a hard look at the Google terms of use.  You may be in violation.

Comment: Thanks Surreal I'm looking in to that right now! I'll post back an edit on how I ended up doing it when I finish it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse all HTML since you need a context-free grammar to do this.

But say you want to parse something, and there are no inner tags in it, you can parse the content using:

```
<a([^>]*)>([^<]*)</a>
```

where the first group will parse the arguments of the `a` tag and the second group the content between the two tags.

In case you are looking for an argument of a tag (say the href of an image), you can use:

```
<img[^>]* src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>
```

where the first group will match with `src` field.